# How to Insert into … Values … Where Value= is equal to given by user? Complex query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I should Insert to `partnerCode` cell where, entered value by user is equal to `randomfield` and it should be Inserted exactly to **opposite** cell where `randomfield=partnerCode`

**For example:** Entered Value is **66666**  it's exist in `randomfield` and inserted to opposite cell

```
   ID      randomfield  partnerCode    
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   1   |  555555     |    null     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   2   |  666666     |   666666    | 
+-------+-------------+-------------+
|   3   |  777777     |    null     |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Html form code:

```
     <form name="Partner" action="../../pages/examples/profile.php" method="POST" >

  <input class="random-but"  name="partnerCode" value="<?php echo $partnerCode; ?>"> 
   <input class="reload-but" type="submit" value=" >>>" name="partnerCode">  



                </form>
```

Here code of Insertion but works incorrect

```
    if (isset($_POST['partnerCode'])) {
      // receive all input values from the form
       $partnerCode= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['partnerCode']);

      $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM refer WHERE partnerCode='$partnerCode' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
      $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



    if (count($errors) == 0) {

     $query = "INSERT INTO refer (randomfield, partnerCode)  
VALUES('$randomfield', '$partnerCode') where 
randomfield='$partnerCode' ";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);  
    }
```

Comment: `INSERT` does not take a `WHERE` clause. You're looking for `UPDATE`

Comment: You should do some error checking (in addition to reviewing some MySQL basics).  `INSERT INTO` shouldn't be followed by a `WHERE`.

Comment: @Patrick Q Yes! That's why I'm looking for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of insert You should use UPDATE

```
    update refer 
    set partnerCode = '$partnerCode' 
    where randomfield='$partnerCode'
```

anyway instead  of php var  in sql and mysqli_real_escape_string  you shold take a look  at your db driver for prepared statements and binding param

Comment: "anyway you should not use php in sql you are at risk for sqlijection .. " What should use alternativly? Any source where I can read about this?

Comment: instead of php var and mysqli_real_escape_string l you should take a look at prepared statements and binding param   https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  ( i see you ahve use mysqli_real_escape_string  for avoid problem ..but prepared statement and binding param is more powerful)